# How can I turn off the notification for the power plug connection?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, 4.1-jelly-bean, notifications, charging

My Samsung Galaxy S3 with Android 4.1 plays a sound every time I connect it to the power plug. Is there a way to turn that off without affecting all other notifications?

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem by doing this:

1. Root the phone
2. Install the [posed Framework](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer) and [Wanam Kit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ma.wanam.xposed). Enable the Wanam Kit module after installing it.
3. Open Wanam Kit and go to the "Sounds" options, then go to the bottom and check "disable low battery sound"
4. Reboot